# how do you pass a generic type to an anonymous function in typescript tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

The following function is failing in a `.tsx` file:

```
export const withComponent = <T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) => (props: any) => (
  <shortcutContext.Consumer>
    {addShortcut => <Component addShortcut={addShortcut} {...props} />}
  </shortcutContext.Consumer>
);
```

With the error `JSX element 'T' has no corresponding closing tag.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a limitation of `.tsx` parser, there is no way to make it interpret this particular `<` as a delimiter for generic parameter instead of start tag.

But for this particular case, the workaround is easy.

`export const` implies this is at the top level, and its implementation does not refer to `this` anyway, so it could be rewritten using an old-style function instead of the  first `=>`:

```
export const withComponent = function<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) { 
    return (props: any) => (
        <shortcutContext.Consumer>
            {addShortcut => <Component addShortcut={addShortcut} {...props} />}
        </shortcutContext.Consumer>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write this way as well:

```
export const withComponent = <T,>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) => (props: any) => (
  <shortcutContext.Consumer>
    {addShortcut => <Component addShortcut={addShortcut} {...props} />}
  </shortcutContext.Consumer>
);
```